# Why is my `minutes` number goes into negatives?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I've been working on a timer for a few weeks now. When I try to subtract minutes from 0, it goes into negatives without touching the hours. I've tried a few methods, read the documentation, and watched several YouTube videos, but none of them help me. Here's the code I used:

```
seconds--;
    if (seconds === 0) {
        seconds = 59;
        minutes--;
        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutesText.innerText = '0' + minutes.toString()
        } else {
            minutesText.innerText = minutes;
        }
        if (minutes === 0) {
            minutes = 59;
            hours--;
            if (hours < 10) {
                hoursText.innerText = '0' + hours.toString()
            } else {
                hoursText.innerText = hours;
            }
            if (hours === 0) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }

    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        secondsText.innerText = '0' + seconds.toString();
    } else {
        secondsText.innerText = seconds;
    }
```

It never touches the `hours--` and doesn't make minutes be equal to 59.

(Sorry if it's an easy fix, I'm just getting started on JS)

Comment: Hint: What does `minutes--` do when `minutes` is `0`? Will `minutes === 0` catch that condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

1. You're updating `minutesText.innerText` *before* you check whether `minutes` is 0 and thus needs to be changed to `59`. It should be after the `if (minutes === 0)` block instead.
2. You need to check if values are `0` *before* you decrement them, otherwise you will never catch the `0` value.

This snippet incorporates those fixes.

```js
let hoursText = document.getElementById('hours');
let minutesText = document.getElementById('minutes');
let secondsText = document.getElementById('seconds');


function updateTimer() {
  hours = +hoursText.innerText;
  minutes = +minutesText.innerText;
  seconds = +secondsText.innerText;
  if (seconds === 0) {
    seconds = 59;
    if (minutes === 0) {
      minutes = 59;
      if (hours === 0) {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        return;
      } else {
        hours--;
      }
      if (hours < 10) {
        hoursText.innerText = '0' + hours.toString()
      } else {
        hoursText.innerText = hours;
      }
    } else {
      minutes--;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
      minutesText.innerText = '0' + minutes.toString()
    } else {
      minutesText.innerText = minutes;
    }
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }
  if (seconds < 10) {
    secondsText.innerText = '0' + seconds.toString();
  } else {
    secondsText.innerText = seconds;
  }
}

interval = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
```

```html
<div><span id="hours">00</span>:<span id="minutes">01</span>:<span id="seconds">13</span></div>
```